# Java EE webapp using servlets and freemarker, trouble including css file

Tags: css, freemarker, servlet-3.0

In a Java EE webapp using servlets and freemarker as view technology, i can't seem to include css files for proper browser render.
I'm only using .ftl for view and i path for css files is inside resources/css, being resources inside 'webapp'.
Tried with straight html `<link...` and using JSTL(not fancy)..but page is rendered without css.
Where i'm wrong at?
Thanks

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @aleksandr-m <link href="/eduict/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> and <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">. The second works if using JSP's, but i prefer sticking only with freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
<link href="./resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can try using url path to CSS, maybe putting it to some properties file and using it as prefix for each CSS include.